# type of expression is ambiguous without more context Swift when using coredata

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting the following error

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

this is occurring in my function where i update my core data.

the update function looks like this:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func updateFriend(studentID: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String,gender: String, courseStudy: String, age: Int, address: String) {
    
      
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Friends> = Friends.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "studentID==\(studentID)")
        do {
            let test = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
            
            let transc = test[0] as NSManagedObject
            transc.setValue(studentID, forKey: "studentID")
            transc.setValue(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
            transc.setValue(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
            transc.setValue(gender, forKey: "gender")
            transc.setValue(courseStudy, forKey: "courseStudy")
            transc.setValue(age, forKey: "age")
            transc.setValue(address, forKey: "address")
            
            do {
                try managedContext.save()
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

and this is how i am using it:

**editFriendClass.swift**

```
import UIKit

class editFriendClass: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var studentID: UITextField!
    var textstr :String?
    var friends: [Friends] = []
    var a:Int? = 0
   
    @IBOutlet weak var study: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var gender: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var age: UITextField!
    
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        studentID.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        studentID.text = textstr;
         a = Int(studentID.text!)
      
        friends = appDelegate.getFriendInfo_single(id: a!)
        
        firstName.text = friends[0].firstName
        lastName.text = friends[0].lastName
        age.text = "\(friends[0].age)"
        gender.text = friends[0].gender
        address.text = friends[0].address
        study.text = friends[0].courseStudy
       
    }
    
    @IBAction func update(_ sender: Any) {
        appDelegate.updateFriend(studentID: a, firstName: firstName.text, lastName: lastName.text, gender: gender.text, courseStudy: study.text, age: age.text, address: address.text)
//        appDelegate.updateFriend(studentID: 111211, firstName: "wil", lastName: "wil", gender: "wil", courseStudy: "wil", age: 32, address: "wil")
    }
    
    
}
```

the error comes at

```
appDelegate.updateFriend(studentID: a, firstName: firstName.text, lastName: lastName.text, gender: gender.text, courseStudy: study.text, age: age.text, address: address.text)
```

but when i replace it will the line commented out below it
it works successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are sending an optional id, `Int?`, to your function that expects a non-optional value, `Int`. Overall you need to handle this optional value better.

In `viewDidLoad` you should handle `id` like this

```
if let id = Int(studentID.text!) {
    let friends = appDelegate.getFriendInfo_single(id: id)

    if !friends.isEmpty {
       firstName.text = friends[0].firstName
       //...
    }
}
```

And your update function should also handle a possible nil value

```
@IBAction func update(_ sender: Any) {
    if let id = Int(studentID.text!) { //or if let id = a
        appDelegate.updateFriend(studentID: id, firstName: firstName.text, lastName: lastName.text, gender: gender.text, courseStudy: study.text, age: age.text, address: address.text)
    }
}
```